# my function save to pickle not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have a script that calls the function below to create a dict from pickle load as in:

```
def load_obj(name ):
    try:
        with open('obj/' + name + '.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
    except:
        return dict(name)
```

I update the pickle loaded dict to add a new key:value record then and save the pickle using this function:

```
def save_obj(obj, name ):
    pathlib.Path('.obj').mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    with open('.obj/'+ name + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

My intention here is to create a dict from the pickle load, add a new key:value to the dict and save the pickle. If the key is already in the pickle loaded dict, I just pass.  My issue is that the save_obj does not seem to save the updated dict to the pickle.  Surely I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated. 
In my testing,  I can see that the length of the dict on load is 1919 and the length of the dict after adding the new record is 1920.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding and saving everything correctly. However, you are not saving the file under the same name you loaded it on. You load the file `obj/test.pkl` and then save it as `.obj/test.pkl`. My guess is your trying to use the current directory notation here so change every `obj/` or `.obj/` to `./obj/`. Also check your file system for the names of all the directories and filenames.

Comment: you found it...   load_obj function I  callout the sub-directory as "obj"  but on the save_obj I callout ".obj/'     I just removed the "." and everything started working as intended.   but I'm not sure why this is the case

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help!